# ELK-Stack: Parse only IP/MAC from Syslog with Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I'm searching for a way to parse IP addresses and MACs from a syslog entry with Logstash. Currently I try to fetch it with GROK, but the problem is, that I might have to match the entire line, instead of just a part of the message itself.

For example I have to following line:

> Apr  9 12:41:01 cn1Label=Host ID dvchost=exch01 TrendMicroDsTenant=Primary 
>   TrendMicroDsTenantId=0 dstMAC=55:C0:A8:55:FF:41
>   srcMAC=CA:36:42:B1:78:3D TrendMicroDsFrameType=IP src=10.0.251.84
>   dst=56.19.41.128 out=166 cs3= cs3Label=Fragmentation Bits proto=ICMP
>   srcPort=0 dstPort=0 cnt=1 act=IDS:Reset cn3=0 cn3Label=DPI Packet
>   Position cs5=0 cs5Label=DPI Stream Position cs6=0 cs6Label=DPI Flags

I wanna fetch the "src" and "dst" IPs and the "srcMAC" and "dstMAC" as well. I would try it like that in Logstash:

```
grok{
  match => { "message" => "src=%{IPV4:src_ip}" }
  match => { "message" => "dst=%{IPV4:dst_ip}" }
  match => { "message" => "srcMAC=%{MAC:src_mac}" }
  match => { "message" => "dstMAC=%{MAC:dst_mac}" }
}
```

But it does not work, because it does not match the whole line. I tried with `.*` and other matching techniques as well, without success.

Is there a way to just parse the IPs like shown without parsing the full line?

I would try to parse other parts of the message, such as protocol as well. The reason why I do not match the full line is, that the some messages are different and need then also another way to extract its values.

Thank you!

Comment: When using more than one pattern in a single grok filter, logstash will try to match each pattern after the other, stopping at the first successful match, which explain why it doesn't work in your case.  But you can have more than one grok filter, with each having a different pattern.

Comment: @baudsp Thank you. I just found the failure as well. Thank you that you mentioned that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution. I did something very wrong. You have to do a matching filter for each matching separately. If I do so, then I can extract also the content within the message field, for example like:

```
grok{match => {"message" => "SRC=%{IPV4:ip}"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [kv filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html) to deal with key-value pairs like like those you have in your log. To only keep the relevant pairs, use the `include_keys` option.

In your case, it would look like this:

```
kv{
    include_keys => [ "src", "dst", "srcMAC", "dstMAC" ]
}
```

Which would result in:

```
{
  "dst": "56.19.41.128",
  "host": "frsred-0077",
  "srcMAC": "CA:36:42:B1:78:3D",
  "dstMAC": "55:C0:A8:55:FF:41"
}
```

One benefit of the kv filter is that you're not dependent on the order of the pairs staying the same, unlike with the grok filter.

Comment: Actually I never used the kv filter, but I gonna try it. Thank you! (-:

Answer (score 0):

The `grok` filter needs to match the whole message, to fetch only a couple of fields you still need to match everything, the following pattern will match your example.

```
%{GREEDYDATA}%{SPACE}dstMAC=%{MAC:dst_mac}%{SPACE}srcMAC=%{MAC:src_mac}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA}%{SPACE}src=%{IP:src_ip}%{SPACE}dst=%{IP:dst_ip}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA}
```

The result will be:

```
{
  "src_ip": "10.0.251.84",
  "src_mac": "CA:36:42:B1:78:3D",
  "dst_mac": "55:C0:A8:55:FF:41",
  "dst_ip": "56.19.41.128"
}
```

This pattern will also match any message with the following format:

```
ANYTHING dstMAC=MACADDRESS srcMAC=MACADDRESS ANYTHING src=IPADDRESS dst=IPADRESS ANYTHING
```

Comment: It is not needed to match the whole message, just like mentioned in my last answer.